# Custom form validation error message for Codeigniter 2

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have a drop down named "business_id".

```
<select name="business_id"> 
    <option value="0">Select Business</option> More options... 
</select>
```

Here comes the validation rule, user must select an option.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('business_id', 'Business', 'greater_than[0]');
```

Problem being the error message says: The Business field must contain a number greater than 0. Not very intuitive! I want it to say "You must select a business".

I tried:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('Business', 'You must select a business');
```

But CI complete ignores this. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try not setting the value attribute on the default select...

```
<select name="business_id"> 
    <option value>Select Business</option> More options... 
</select>
```

and then just using required for your form validation rule...

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('business_id', 'Business', 'required');
```

I suppose you could try editing the way that you're trying to set the message also...

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('business_id', 'You must select a business');
instead of
$this->form_validation->set_message('Business', 'You must select a business');
```

I'm not entirely sure if that will do the trick though.

Comment: I already tried your second suggestion which failed. Your first suggestion will work, but I feel I "give in" to the code if I use that. I'm still looking to set a custom error message.

Comment: After looking closer at the docs.  It looks like the first argument passed to set_message should be the rule name instead of the field name.  Try passing greater_than or required as the first argument to set_message depending on which rule you decide to go with to override the default message.

Comment: That did it!$this->form_validation->set_message('greater_than', 'Your must select a business'); not $this->form_validation->set_message('greater_than[0]', 'Your must select a business'); as I tried before. Thank you!!!

Comment: I jumped the gun, it caused complications. I have two drop down in the form: $this->form_validation->set_message('greater_than', 'Your must select an access level');

   $this->form_validation->set_rules('business_id', 'Business', 'trim|required|greater_than[0]');
   $this->form_validation->set_message('greater_than', 'Your must select a business');. When access_level fails for not being selected, the error is "You must select a business". Does anyone have a remedy for this.

Comment: @pigfox You could either use your own [callback functions](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks) for each of those rules and set the error messages for each field in their respective function, extend CodeIgniter's [form validation library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html), or use the info that's provided in this thread and use the required rule to validate one input and greater_than to validate the other (thus avoiding the message collision).

Comment: @Anthony_jack, if got this one to work:$this->form_validation->set_rules('access_level', 'Access Level', 'trim|required|greater_than[0]');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('business_id', 'Business', 'trim|required|greater_than[0]');
   $this->form_validation->set_message('greater_than', 'Your must select %s');
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same requirement for adding [custom form validation error messages in codeigniter 2](http://ajmm.org/2011/07/custom-form-validation-error-messages-in-codeigniter-2/) (e.g. "You must agree to our Terms & Conditions"). Naturally it would be wrong to override the error messages for require and greater_than as it would erroneously produce messages for the rest of the form. I extended the CI_Form_validation class and have overridden the set_rules method to accept a new 'message' parameter:

```
<?php

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{
    private $_custom_field_errors = array();

    public function _execute($row, $rules, $postdata = NULL, $cycles = 0)
    {
        // Execute the parent method from CI_Form_validation.
        parent::_execute($row, $rules, $postdata, $cycles);

        // Override any error messages for the current field.
        if (isset($this->_error_array[$row['field']])
            && isset($this->_custom_field_errors[$row['field']]))
        {
            $message = str_replace(
                '%s',
                !empty($row['label']) ? $row['label'] : $row['field'],
                $this->_custom_field_errors[$row['field']]);

            $this->_error_array[$row['field']] = $message;
            $this->_field_data[$row['field']]['error'] = $message;
        }
    }

    public function set_rules($field, $label = '', $rules = '', $message = '')
    {
        $rules = parent::set_rules($field, $label, $rules);

        if (!empty($message))
        {
            $this->_custom_field_errors[$field] = $message;
        }

        return $rules;
    }
}

?>
```

With the above class you would produce your rule with a custom error message like so:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('business_id', 'Business', 'greater_than[0]', 'You must select a business');
```

You may also use '%s' in your custom message which will automatically fill in the label of fieldname.

Comment: I already had a `MY_Form_validation` class in my libraries folder with a custom `valid_url()` fuction I wrote. I tried adding the rest of this code to that file but it wouldn't work. I tried adding a `message` key with a value in my validation array but the new message did not show. I utilized this in the "Terms of Service" field so the only rule I have for this particular field is "required" Any insight as to what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

If you'd like to customize the error messages that are displayed with each rule, you can find them in an array at:

```
/system/language/english/form_validation_lang.php
```

Answer (score 1):

You should extend the Form_validation library as Anthony said.

For instance, I do something like this in a file called `MY_Form_validation.php` which should be put on `/application/libraries`

```
function has_selection($value, $params)
{
    $CI =& get_instance();

    $CI->form_validation->set_message('has_selection', 'The %s need to be selected.');

    if ($value == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

In your case, because your first option (Guidance option - Please select ...) has the value of `0`, you may want to change the conditional statement from `-1` to `0`. Then, from now on, you could have this line to check selection value:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('business_id', 'Business', 'has_selection');
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple CI2 callback function that I used. I wanted something other than just 'required' as a default param of the validation. The documentation helps: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks

```
    public function My_form() {

        ...Standard CI validation stuff...
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('business_id', 'Business', 'callback_busid');
        ...

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            return false; 
    }
    else {
        ...process the form...
        $this->email->send();
        }
    } // Close My_form method

    // Callback method
    function busid($str) {

        if ($str == '') {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('business_id', 'Choose a business, Mang!');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else {
        return TRUE;
    }
         } // Close the callback method
```

For your case you could change the callback to check for `if($str<0)` - I'm assuming you've used numbers in your selection/dropdown menu.

If the callback returns false, the form is held and the error message is shown. Otherwise, it's passed and sent to the 'else' of the `form method`.

Answer (score 1):

A little hack might not good for you but I have done this for a little change.

Example,
I want to change message 'The Email field must be a unique value'.

I have done this as

```
<?php
$error = form_error('email');
echo str_replace('field must be a unique value', 'is already in use.', $error); 
// str_replace('string to search/compare', 'string to replace with', 'string to search in')
?>
```

If string found then it prints our custom message else it will display error message as it is like 'The Email field must be a valid email' etc...

Answer (score 1):

for those of you working on CodeIgniter 3 you can do the following:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('business_id', 'Business', 'greater_than[0]', array(
'greater_than' => 'You must select a business',
));
```

And if you are using CodeIgniter 2, you will need to extend and override the CI_Form_validation class (https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html for more info on how to do so) with the new CodeIgniter 3 CI_Form_validation class and use the function above.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the rule is the last parameter.

Please try:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('greater_than[0]', 'You must select a business');
```

More info:
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#validationrules

Answer (score 0):

I extended the form_validation library with a simple function that makes sure a drop down box does not have its default value selected. Hope this helps.

**application/libraries/MY_Form_validation.php**

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed.');

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->CI->lang->load('MY_form_validation');
    }

     /**
     * Make sure a drop down field doesn't have its default value selected.
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string
     * @param   field
     * @return  bool
     * @author  zechdc
     */
    function require_dropdown($str, $string_to_compare)
    {   
        return ($str == $string_to_compare) ? FALSE : TRUE;
    }
}
```

**application/language/english/MY_Form_validation_lang.php**

```
$lang['require_dropdown']   = 'The %s field must have an item selected.';
```

### **How to Use:**

1) Make your form drop down box:

```
<select name="business_id"> 
    <option value="select">Select Business</option> More options... 
</select>
```

2) Create Validation Rule. You might be able to set the value to 0 and use require_dropdown[0] but I've never tried that.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('business_id', 'Business', 'require_dropdown[select]');
```

3) Set your custom message: (Or skip this step and use the one in the language file.)

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('business_id', 'You must select a business');
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Method username_check call back function

### 01.

```
public function username_check($str)
{
    if ($str=="")
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'Merci d’indiquer le nombre d’adultes');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

--
02. Then Put this Validation Code on your class

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('number_adults', 'Label Name','Your Message',) 'callback_username_check');
```

This may help you