# Is there a way to change the output of validation_errors() in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, validation, authentication, customization

I'm working on a login-functionality for a user in Codeigniter.

This is part of my User-controller:

```
public function login() {
    $name = $this->input->post('username');
    $pass = $this->input->post('pass');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Användarnamn', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'Lösenord', 'required');

    //Username or password not given
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
            $succesful = false;                        
    }
    else {
            //Form itself validates (Username and password is given)
            //Check if username and password matches against some user in the database
            $um = new Usermodel();
            $um->setUsername($name);
            $um->setPassword($pass);

            //True if account exists or false if it does not
            $succesful = $um->accountExists(); 
    }

    $data = array();
    $succesful = false; //TEMP
    if ($succesful === false) {
            $data['error'] = 'groovy';
            $this->form_validation->set_message('username', 'groovy' );                        
    }

    //Show template
    $data['loginform'] = $this->loginform();
    $data['registerform'] = $this->registerform();
    $this->load->view('home', $data);
}
```

Snippet from my view (home) looks like:

```
<?php 
echo validation_errors(); //Show errors if they occur on submit
if (isset($error)) {
    echo $error;
}
if (isset($loginform)) {
    echo $loginform;
}
if (isset($registerform)) {
    echo $registerform;   
}                
?>
```

When a user hits submit on the loginform, the `login()` function is called. If login fails with match of user from database, then the word groovy is echoed out.

Is there a way to do acheive this **WITHOUT** using `$data['error'] = 'groovy'` ?

What I want to do is to replace:

```
echo validation_errors(); //Show errors if they occur on submit
if (isset($error)) {
    echo $error;
}
```

with

```
echo validation_errors(); //Show errors if they occur on submit
```

in my view (where `validation_errors()` should return groovy)

This just specifies value when input username is incorrectly (based on the rules) if I understand correctly.

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('username', 'groovy' );
```

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108718/how-can-i-setup-custom-error-messages-for-each-form-field-in-codeigniter

Comment: No, not really. I just wondered if this was possible. I think NOT because the validation of the actual form is correct (username and password is submitted). I want to echo out a message when these don't match against my database.

Comment: We have a codeigniter site with a custom library called MY_Form_validation and in it we have custom functions with validation checks.  I think maybe this question will help with that actually: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839327/custom-form-validation-error-message-for-codeigniter-2.  And there's a link in the answer there to this blog with more info: http://ajmm.org/2011/07/custom-form-validation-error-messages-in-codeigniter-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the Form Validation class and add a custom function to add messages to the error array (which is where `validation_errors()` gets its messages);

libraries/MY_Form_validation.php

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{
    public function add_error($field, $message)
    {
        if ( ! isset($this->_error_array[$field]))
        {
            $this->_error_array[$field] = $message;
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

controller:

```
$succesful = false; //TEMP
if ($succesful === false) {
        $this->form_validation->add_error('username', 'Username is groovy!');                        
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I haven't tested the code, but I understand exactly what you mean and this will do the trick! Thanks!